# Animating UIButton inside UICollectionView doesn't work for the first init if using cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view (`self.myCollectionView`) contained inside a main window with another view. I'm getting the collection cell at the path at where the touch ended. For this portion, the code works just fine. However, when I'm trying to animate a button inside the cell `cell.btn`, it doesn't work until I re-init the view.

```
//touch ended
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] firstObject];
    CGPoint p = [self.window convertPoint:[touch locationInView:touch.window] toView:self.myCollectionView];
    NSIndexPath *idx = [self.myCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (idx){
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:idx];
        //Successfully getting the cell
        [self animateButton:cell.btn];
        //This doesn't work until the view is re-init/reload
    }
}

//The animation method
-(void)animateButton:(UIButton *)sender{
        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        [anim setDuration:0.05];
        [anim setRepeatCount:5];
        [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
        [anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                             CGPointMake(sender.center.x - 5,sender.center.y)]];
        [anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                           CGPointMake(sender.center.x + 5, sender.center.y)]];
        [anim.layer removeAllAnimations];
        [anim.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
 }
```

I've tested with the `[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(animateButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]` method, and when passing the `sender` to `animateButton:`, it works every time.

Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what may be going on, but I'd think this would work better, and be much easier to manage, if you had that *inside your cell class* rather than in your view controller.

Comment: That actually fixed it, though I needs to add observer for each cell, directly calling the method doesn't work, very weird.